# Find files that have words in common

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing

What would be the best way to create a list of files that have common words with a given file. For example, if I had:

```
$ ls
  mainFile  file1  file2  file file4
$ cat mainFile
  exquisite malicious sentient pulsating
  perspicacious one
  tawdry fumigate Baryshnikov O'connor
```

and I wanted to list any of the files in the `cwd` that contained any one of the words in `mainFile`. What would be the best way to go about this?

Since the number of words per line in `mainFile` is not constant, I was finding solutions using `cut` a little tricky. I was trying to create a string out of the words and then place them separated by `|` in a `grep -l "exquisite|malicious|etc" *` command. I'm open to any method though that might be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First generate indices for mainFile,

`sed 's/ /\n/g' mainFile | sort | uniq > mainFile.idx`

Then do a grep for fixed strings:

`grep -F -f mainFile.idx file*`

Comment: This is great. I am extracting the base file name with the following: `sed 's/:.*//' | sed 's/.*\///'`; is this a good way to do it? I couldn't seem to find a switch that would just output base filename.

Comment: @stariz77 not sure if I get your script, but to get the base name, use `basename /path/to/file`

Comment: you understood it fine. Just the output from your command is `/path/to/file/file1:tawdry malicious`, i.e., path and list of words found. I just want the filename (basename) and no list of found words. I thought maybe there was a way to to specify this output with your solution or something.

Comment: @stariz77 I seems to get it, to retrieve the file name in that situation, use `awk -F ':' { print $1 }`

Comment: or use the `-l` option to `grep`. Also, it's not going to match words. So if for instance mainfile contains "one", it will match all files that contain "gone", "honey"... See the "-w" option for that. Also note that `\n` in the RHS of sed's `s` command is not standard (you can use `tr` instead). Also note that you don't need the temporary file, you can use `-f <(...)` or pass the list of words on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

If your `grep` supports the non-standard `-w` option (for matching words):

```
grep -lwFe "$(tr -cs "[[:alnum:]_'-]" '[\n*]' < mainfile | sort -u)" file*
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
    for pattern in `cat mainfile`
    do
    grep -l "$pattern" file*
    done
```

ARUN